# extract decorating nodes if it exists but still return path if decorating nodes does not exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph

```
                     (y1:Y) 
                     ^
                     |
(a1:A) -> (b1:B) -> (c1:C) 


                    (e1:E)
                     ^
                     |
                    (d1:D)
                     ^
                     |
(a2:A) -> (b2:B) -> (c2:C) 


(a3:A) -> (b3:B) -> (c3:C)
```

I would like to find path between node label A and C. I can use the query

```
match p=((:A)-[*]->(:C))
return p
```

But I also want to get node label Y and node label D, E if these decorating nodes exists. If I try:

```
match p=((:A)-[*]->(cc:C)), (cc)-->(yy:Y), (cc)-[*]->(dd:D)-[*]->(ee:E)
return p, yy, dd, ee
```

Then it is only going to return the path if the C node has Y, D, E connects to it.

The output that I need is:

```
a1->b1->c1, y1, null
a2->b2->c2, null, [[d1, e1]]
a3->b3->c3, null, null
```

I.e., if decorating node does not exist, then just return null. For the array, it can be null or empty array. Also D and E nodes will be group into an array of arrays since there could be many pairs of D and E.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, returning an empty array for the deDecoration if there aren't any D-E decorations

```
MATCH p=((:A)-[*]->(c:C))
WITH p, 
     HEAD([(c)--(y:Y) | y ])  AS yDecoration,
     [(c)-[*]->(d:D)-[*]->(e:E) | [d,e]] AS deDecoration

RETURN p, yDecoration, deDecoration
```

with this graph (multiple D-E)

[image]

this query

```
MATCH p=((:A)-[*]->(c:C))
WITH REDUCE(s='' , node IN nodes(p) | s + CASE WHEN s='' THEN '' ELSE '->' END + node.name) AS p, 
     HEAD([(c)--(y:Y) | y.name ])  AS yDecoration,
     [(c)-[*]->(d:D)-[*]->(e:E) | [d.name,e.name]] AS deDecoration

 RETURN p, yDecoration, deDecoration
```

returns

```
╒════════════╤═════════════╤═════════════════════════╕
│"p"         │"yDecoration"│"deDecoration"           │
╞════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════════════════╡
│"A2->B2->C2"│null         │[]                       │
├────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
│"A1->B1->C1"│null         │[["D2","E2"],["D1","E1"]]│
├────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
│"A3->B3->C3"│"Y1"         │[]                       │
└────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558871/returning-a-subgraph-related-to-the-path I think you might be interested in this :)